# internally redirecting to another file in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want that a url http://domain.com/sitemap.xml internally points to a file sitemap_book.xml in htdocs without any 301/302 redirects.

Please suggest a Rewrite Rule for the same.

I came up with

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} "sitemap.xml"
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sitemap_book.xml [R]
```

but it doesn't work without [R]. Gives 400 bad request

When I use [P], I get 502 Proxy Error. I tried setting up mod_proxy with following code

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
ProxyRequests On

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Proxy>
</IfModule>
```

That gives 403 Forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

*REQUEST_FILENAME* is always an absolute filesystem path while *REQUEST_URI* is always an absolute URL path. So your example would rather work with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} =/sitemap.xml` (`=`: lexicographical comparison) or even directly in the `RewriteRule` pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^/sitemap\.xml$ sitemap_book.xml
```

Furthermore the `R` flag is always causing an external redirect rather than an internal. So just leave it away:

```
RewriteRule ^/sitemap\.xml$ sitemap_book.xml
```

Comment: This isn't working either. It says 400 Bad Request. Works when I add [R] to make it an external redirect. 
Any ideas why apache isn't picking up the internal redirect?